# Detect if iPhone is rotating as it's rotating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which will update the background image of my page when you rotate it a certain way:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() {
    var orientation = window.orientation;
    switch (orientation) {
    case 0:
        $(".bg-img").css("background-image", "url(" + portrait + ")");
        break;
    case 90:
        $(".bg-img").css("background-image", "url(" + landscape + ")");
        break;
    case -90:
        $(".bg-img").css("background-image", "url(" + landscape + ")");
        break;
    };
};​
```

This works, but when the page is rotated, it takes a few seconds to load the new image, and causes the page to look odd.

Is there anyway to detect that the orientation is changing, instead of changed? Something like `willAnimateFirstHalfOfRotationToInterfaceOrientation`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`deviceorientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Detecting_device_orientation) event fires with updates to the current position of the device.  [Here's a demo.](http://www.jeremyselier.com/s/demo/device_orientation.html)

Note that this only works on iPhone ≥ 4 and iPad ≥ 2.  Older Apple hardware doesn't have a gyroscope.

The event also worked on my Galaxy Nexus Android 4 device in Chrome and the stock browser.

You could also [preload](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=image%20preload) your background images so that the switch occurs instantly.

Comment: I wish there was a way to get the moment when the screen rotates, as it rotates about 45 degrees, but the callback for `onorientationchange` is fired when it's fully turned. I think at least. I'm trying to use `deviceorientation`, but it's persnickety when you turn the device quickly.

Comment: To be honest, the best solution is probably to just preload your different background images so that when you do switch them in `onorientationchange`, the change is instant.  Trying to anticipate the rotation with `deviceorientation` is most likely just going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Well the images are `data:url`'s, and I was just retrieving their value from `localStorage` each time the page turned. Would it make more sense to assign them to a variable on page load, then call that variable instead?

Comment: Interesting.  I was assuming that the URLs were on remote servers, and the download of images was the reason for the delay.  I doubt you'd get very much gain, but you can't know until you try.

Comment: The only reason I am using them is because I didn't feel like allowing the user to upload a background image to my server, instead, they just "upload it", and it stores the image in LS. Except I already am setting the LS values to a variable: `var portrait = localStorage.getItem("portrait");`, so I don't know how else I can make the transition smoother.

Comment: Try: `window.onorientationchange=function() { $('.bg-img').css('background-image','none'); setTimeout(function() { /* current orientation code here */ }, 10); };`  This will first clear the background before trying to load the next one.  This will allow you to see if your loading code is taking too long.  (The timeout is to allow the browser a chance to render before loading.)

Comment: I ended up just fading the image with `-webkit-transition:background 1000ms`.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to hook on the `deviceorientation` event, which triggers on every motion and not only on full changes. See those articles:

- [W3 DeviceOrientation Event Specification Draft](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation)
- [html5rocks: Using Device Orientation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/)
- [MDN: Detecting device orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Detecting_device_orientation)